# Android ActivityRecognitionApi requestActivityUpdates are too frequent. How can I throttle them?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to change how often I request location updates from the FusedLocationProviderAPI based on the activity level of the user. Android provides an ActivityRecognitionApi which would be great, but unfortunately:

"Activities may be received more frequently than the detectionIntervalMillis parameter if another application has also requested activity updates at a faster rate." (From: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi.html)

I'd like to execute code no more often than once every, say, 10 seconds. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably found a solution by now, but..

I am currently working on a fork of https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation trying to add Activity Recognition. Using an RxJava observer, you easily define a filter that only let new activities go to the subscribe() method if x seconds has passed.

The fork can be found here: https://github.com/cyrixmorten/Android-ReactiveLocation

Comment: Just to let you know if you are testing it out, it is still highly alpha and opened an issue about it here: https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation/issues/21. In short it is currently limited to having one observer for activity detection.