# Google Activity Recognition API called too frequently

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client, activity-recognition

Im trying to use Google Activity Recognition API, and get only results when activity changes or about every 30mins (+- 10mins or more if Activity does not change). Instead, when I call the piece of code below, I get Activity Recognition results very often in my `IntentService`, like every minute:

```
ActivityRecognition
            .ActivityRecognitionApi
            .requestActivityUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, 60000 * 30, getSensingServicePendingIntent())
            .setResultCallback(this);
```

The method to create `PendingIntent` object:

```
private PendingIntent getSensingServicePendingIntent(Integer userLabel) {
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, SenseDataIntentService.class);

    return PendingIntent
            .getService(mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

The method to get`GoogleApiClient`:

```
 private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
            .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    return mGoogleApiClient;
}
```

I know that [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi) says this:

> Activities may be received more frequently than the detectionIntervalMillis parameter if another application has also requested activity updates at a faster rate. It may also receive updates faster when the activity detection service receives a signal that the current activity may change, such as if the device has been still for a long period of time and is then unplugged from a phone charger.

But I just think that I get the updates too frequently (even if activity does not change). Any solutions, as I want to save some battery drainage.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500602/android-activityrecognitionapi-requestactivityupdates-are-too-frequent-how-can

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured that out. Google Fit was running in the background and it was constantly listening to activity changes. Therefore, I got all those results as well (as it is written in the documentation).